# Private messages organisation model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, message

I'm going to organise social network. So the question is: how the tables responsible for private maessages should be organised : (1) one table for each user, (2) one table for 1000 users or it's better (3) to create one table for all the user's messages, considering that the system is high loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plan small and use a single table. Worry about scale when you get there. The problems you encounter in 6 months will not be the problems you're thinking about today.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm going to organise social network.

Omg, another one!

You should use NoSQL and caching solutions like mongodb or membase to be prepared for high load. If you still want to stick to postgres, you should create a [partitioned](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Table_partitioning) table.

Comment: I know about NoSQL solutions, but are you sure that you can organize a good full-text search?

Comment: SQL is a good all-in-one solution. Yes, it has FTS, and it works roughly well, but specialized solutions like Solr would do better.